# search algorithm BFS?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

So i have a recursive search algorithm here,

```
Search(graph G = (V, E), vertex s ∈ V, integer k)
1 mark vertex s as number k
2 set k ← k + 1
3 let L be the linked list of neighbors for s
4 repeat until all entries in L are marked with an X
5 mark the first un-marked entry y in L with an X (going from left to right in the list)
6 let v be the vertex named in entry y
7 if v is not yet marked with a number then set k ← Search(G, v, k)
8 return k
```

Here's the adjacency list box diagram,

[image]

It seems to me that it is a Breadth-First-Search since it visits the nodes at level k before the nodes of level k+1. Depth-First-Search would explore as far as possible along each branch before backtracking. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is depth first search. You recursively explore children before siblings.

btw, if someones claims they have a recursive algorithm for breadth-first-search, you should look at it carefully. Either it is wrong, or a convoluted simulation of no use.